# FuelSDK-Python: Creating and performing an EmailSendDefinition?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I'm trying to send an Email to a List using the Python FuelSDK. Since I also have to control the **FromAddress**, the documentation seemed to indicate that I needed a *EmailSendDefinition* rather than the simpler *Send* object. What I'm struggling with is performing that *EmailSendDefinition*.

Since the *EmailSendDefinition* object is not defined in the base FuelSDK-Python, I have added the following code:

```
class ET_Perform(ET_Constructor):

    def __init__(self, auth_stub, action, options=None, definitions=()):
        auth_stub.refresh_token()

        parsed_options = self.parse_props_into_ws_object(auth_stub, 'PerformOptions', options) if options else None
        parsed_definitions = [self.parse_props_into_ws_object(auth_stub, obj_type, props) for obj_type, props in definitions]

        response = auth_stub.soap_client.service.Perform(parsed_options, action, parsed_definitions)
        if response is not None:
            super(ET_Perform, self).__init__(response)


class ET_EmailSendDefinition(ET_CUDSupport):

    obj_type = 'EmailSendDefinition'

    def perform(self):
        self.obj = ET_Perform(self.auth_stub, 'start', definitions=((self.obj_type, self.props),))
        return self.obj
```

I then proceed to create an *EmailSendDefinition*, assigning it a known **CustomerKey** for later reference:

```
email_send_def_key = unicode(uuid.uuid4())
email_send_definition = ET_EmailSendDefinition()
email_send_definition.auth_stub = client
email_send_definition.props = {
    'Name': email_send_def_key,
    'CustomerKey': email_send_def_key,
    'Email': {
        'ID': new_email_id
    },
    'SendDefinitionList': [{
        'List': {
            'ID': list_id
        },
        'DataSourceTypeID': 'List'
    }],
    'SendClassification': {
        'CustomerKey': 'Default Commercial'
    }
}

if from_email:
    email_send_definition.props['SenderProfile'] = {
        'FromAddress': from_email
    }

response = email_send_definition.post()
```

I get a successful response from that call. I then proceed to perform that definition, like so:

```
email_def = ET_EmailSendDefinition()
email_def.auth_stub = client
email_def.props = {
    'CustomerKey': email_send_def_key
}
response = email_def.perform()
```

This, however, gets me a 500 Internal Server Error as a response. So instead, I tried to create a *PerformRequestMsg* object. Here's the code I used:

```
class ET_PerformRequestMsg(FuelSDK.ET_CUDSupport):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ET_PerformRequestMsg, self).__init__()
        self.obj_type = 'PerformRequestMsg'

email_def = ET_EmailSendDefinition()
email_def.auth_stub = client
email_def.props = {
    'CustomerKey': email_send_def_key
}

msg = ET_PerformRequestMsg()
msg.auth_stub = client
msg.props = {
    'Action': 'start',
    'Definitions': [email_def]
}
response = msg.post()
```

This failed as well, complaining of not being able to find the type *APIObject*, which appears to be pretty well defined in the WSDL. This alternative also failed:

```
msg = ET_PerformRequestMsg()
msg.auth_stub = client
msg.props = {
    'Action': 'start',
    'Definitions': [{
        'EmailSendDefinition' : {
            'CustomerKey': email_send_def_key
        }
    }]
}
response = msg.post()
```

It raised errors about type *EmailSendDefinition* not being found as well.

Am I going about this the wrong way, or am I missing something crucial here?

Thanks in advance,