# FuelSDK-Python: Performing an EmailSendDefinition with a specific Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel-sdk, python, send-definition

There is an old old [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27457/fuelsdk-python-creating-and-performing-an-emailsenddefinition) about this and Salesforce hasn't being nice enough to extend their Python SDK (though the PHP and C# ones are way ahead).

I can create the data extension but I'm not able to retrieve a EmailSendDefinition, set the DataExtension and perform it.

Can anyone point me into the right direction to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately it's going to be a while before the Python SDK gets updated.  Are you open to other SDKs or using SOAP/REST directly?

Comment: Right now, I'm going to mix Python with PHP, it seems like the shortest path to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by mixing Python and PHP... Thank God for Docker

```
subprocess.call([
                    'php', 
                    '../php/send_email_to_data_extension.php', 
                    '--sf_secret',            sf_client_secret,
                    '--sf_id',                sf_client_id,
                    '--email_definition_key', send_definition_template_key,
                    '--data_extension_key',   data_extension_key
                    ])
```

```php
# send_email_to_data_extension.php
# Run the composer require stuff
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
use FuelSdk\ET_Client;
use FuelSdk\ET_Email_SendDefinition;


class EmailToDataExtensionSender{
    public $salesforceClient;

    public function __construct($id, $secret){
        $this->salesforceClient = new ET_Client(true, false, ['clientid' => $id,'clientsecret' => $secret]);    
    }

    public function sendEmailToDataExtension($emailCustomerKey, $dataExtensionCustomerKey){
        # Look for the sendemail definition template
        $emailSendDefinition = new ET_Email_SendDefinition();
        $emailSendDefinition->authStub = $this->salesforceClient;
        $emailSendDefinition->props = ['Client.ID', 'CreatedDate','ModifiedDate','ObjectID','CustomerKey','Name','CategoryID','Description','SendClassification.CustomerKey','SenderProfile.CustomerKey','SenderProfile.FromName','SenderProfile.FromAddress','DeliveryProfile.CustomerKey','DeliveryProfile.SourceAddressType','DeliveryProfile.PrivateIP','DeliveryProfile.DomainType','DeliveryProfile.PrivateDomain','DeliveryProfile.HeaderSalutationSource','DeliveryProfile.FooterSalutationSource','SuppressTracking','IsSendLogging','Email.ID','BccEmail','AutoBccEmail','TestEmailAddr','EmailSubject','DynamicEmailSubject','IsMultipart','IsWrapped','SendLimit','SendWindowOpen','SendWindowClose','DeduplicateByEmail','ExclusionFilter','Additional'];
        $emailSendDefinition->filter = ['Property' => 'CustomerKey','SimpleOperator' => 'equals','Value' => $emailCustomerKey];
        $getResult = $emailSendDefinition->get();
        if($getResult->status && count($getResult->results) == 1){
            # Create a temporary copy of it and change the data extension for the desired one
            $emailSendDefinition->props["Name"] = $getResult->results[0]->Name . "_TMP";
            $emailSendDefinition->props["CustomerKey"] = $getResult->results[0]->CustomerKey . "_TMP";
            $emailSendDefinition->props["PartnerKey"] = $getResult->results[0]->PartnerKey;
            $emailSendDefinition->props["CategoryID"] = $getResult->results[0]->CategoryID;
            $emailSendDefinition->props["SendDefinitionList"] = ["CustomerKey"=> $dataExtensionCustomerKey, "DataSourceTypeID"=>"CustomObject"];
            $emailSendDefinition->props["SendClassification"] = ["CustomerKey" => $getResult->results[0]->SendClassification->CustomerKey];
            $emailSendDefinition->props["Email"] = (array)$getResult->results[0]->Email;
            $postResult = $emailSendDefinition->post();
            if ($postResult->status) { 
                # Perform the send
                $sendResult = $emailSendDefinition->send();
                if ($sendResult->status) { 
                    # Delete the temporary one afterwards
                    $emailSendDefinition->delete();
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to send using send definition due to:".print_r($sendResult,true));
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Unable to create send definition due to: ".print_r($postResult,true));
            } 
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unable to create send definition due to: ".print_r($getResult,true));
        }
    }
}


# Run forest run!
$longArgumentList = [
    "sf_id:", 
    "sf_secret:",
    "email_definition_key:",
    "data_extension_key:"
];
$opts = getopt("",$longArgumentList);
// var_dump($opts);

$sender = new EmailToDataExtensionSender($opts['sf_id'], $opts['sf_secret']);

$sender->sendEmailToDataExtension($opts['email_definition_key'], $opts['data_extension_key']);
```

[image: Yeah]